# How to use Intel SGX platform services with Hyperledger Sawtooth?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth, sgx

I am trying to use hyperledger-sawtooth along side intel sgx. 
I have installed the sawtooth on ubuntu machine but i am trying to figure out how to use intel sgx alongside it ? What are the benefits of using it alongside sgx services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update]

Here are unique benefits one can get with the Intel SGX alongside Hyperledger Sawtooth

PoET Consensus in SGX mode: PoET is a scalable consensus algorithm, if it is configured to run in SGX mode then you get Byzantine Fault Tolerance (BFT) feature. The other BFT algorithms do not scale up to work with larger networks. For example,  PBFT would require a fully connected network in place unlike PoET. Though PBFT is good enough for smaller networks (even 20 nodes). The comparison is another topic altogether and I'll not answer it here.

Private Transaction Family: The ability to protect the privacy of the data, data at storage is encrypted, an out of the band mechanism to read the data with permissionning, ability to verify that the smart contract/ transaction processor running on another party's machine is a valid agreed upon code.

[Original Answer]

Probably this is what you're looking for https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/configure_sgx.html

The document explains how to configure PoET to run on Intel SGX. Since you're asking the question to know how to use Intel SGX alongside the Hyperledger Sawtooth,  there's one more Hyperledger Labs project which provides Private Transaction Family. More information on that can be found here https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/private-transaction-families

Hope this gives you better understanding. Feel free to add more information to the question or ask what is needed on top of this.

Comment: added more comments to question

Comment: I added additional details in my answer